# .htaccess can't parse PHP in HTML files in the root folder

Tags: php, html, apache, parsing, .htaccess

I'm trying to parse PHP code inside .HTML files.

I have added the following code to the .htaccess file in the root folder:

```
...
    <FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
    </FilesMatch>
...
```

All the files outside the root folder are working fine when I made this change.

That is, these html files are parsing the PHP correctly without any issues:

- somedomain/contact/index.html
- somedomain/about-us/index.html

While the homepage is not:

- somedomain/index.html

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thx.
V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding .* at the start should solve this issue

```
<FilesMatch ".*\.(htm|html|php)$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>
```