# Executing HTML as PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

When I try to embed PHP into an HTML file, it doesn't work. I edited my .htaccess so that it treats HTML files as PHP, but when I try to visit the .html file my browser downloads it instead of parsing and displaying it.

EDIT: My .htaccess contents:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess can't parse PHP in HTML files in the root folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755794/htaccess-cant-parse-php-in-html-files-in-the-root-folder)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
RemoveHandler .php .html
<FilesMatch "\.(php|html)$">
SetHandler x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

EDIT:

Depending on your host, you may need to modify it a bit such as:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html
RemoveHandler .php .html
<FilesMatch "\.(php|html)$">
SetHandler x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>
```

OR

```
AddType php5-script .php .html
RemoveHandler .php .html
<FilesMatch "\.(php|html)$">
SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Hm. It doesn't download anymore, now it just doesn't work. The php doesn't execute, but the HTML loads fine. If I rename it to whatever.php, it downloads it.

Comment: Who's your host?  Could need a slight variation of the above to make it work.

Comment: Stupidly enough, none of those work. It tries to download it.

Comment: Are you going to the file directly such as yourdomain.com/index.html or are you just going to yourdomain.com?  The reason I ask is the above may need to be adjusted if no filename is in the url.

Comment: Are you sure that htaccess files are allowed?  In the httpd.conf file it needs to have AllowOverride set to something other than None.  If it's a shared server, you won't be able to access this, but can ask your host if htaccess files are allowed.  You could also just try other htaccess commands to see if they work.

Comment: .htaccess files are definately allowed. If I add a 301 redirect, it works. The one thing I could think of is that mod_php does not exist. But that's unlikely.